# Unable to create lockable file (using Laravel 8 and PHP 7.4)

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-8, php-7.4

I recently created a cache locking mechanism in our system to prevent race conditions. Most of the time, it works just fine (it creates a lock that is released after a certain period of time):

```php
$lockedDriver = Cache::lock('book_driver_' . $driverData['id'], 15);
```

But sometimes, it causes errors like these:

> Unable to create lockable file: /home/backridepal/public_html/storage/framework/cache/data/6a/44/6a441d0a993f4942895df68b5d5cb8d8e439a274. Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Unable to create lockable file: /home/backridepal/public_html/storage/framework/cache/data/6a/44/6a441d0a993f4942895df68b5d5cb8d8e439a274. Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location. at /home/backridepal/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php:73)

> file_put_contents(/home/backridepal/public_html/storage/framework/cache/datas/19/b8/19b8d39dc21197ef4f2f04faec3709e58764c278): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"userId":7035,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_put_contents(/home/backridepal/public_html/storage/framework/cache/datas/19/b8/19b8d39dc21197ef4f2f04faec3709e58764c278): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /home/backridepal/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:187)

So what I did was inspect my cache driver's path (I use `file` value in `config/cache.php` by the way). I executed `ls -l storage/framework/cache/datas` in the terminal to check file permissions and found out that some files are owned by `root` instead of `backridepal`. I don't know what's causing other cache files to be owned by `root` instead of `backridepal`, I hope you can help me with this one.

Before I asked for help here, I already tried other solutions like running `chown -R backridepal:backridepal storage/framework/cache` and running `sudo chmod -R 775 storage` as `root` user, but the errors I mentioned above still rarely occur.

Comment: You must be running some jobs, crons, queues, tests, console commands under root that run the locking code. You can add some logging around the cache calls to figure out what's going on by reading stack traces in these logs.